# Select a value and update status in one query

Tags: mysql

I want to select first available value `'name'` and set it as taken. Is it possible to do it in one query?

This is what I would do in two queries:

```
my_table
id, name, active

$sql="SELECT id, name FROM my_table WHERE active='N' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$id=$row["id"];
$name=$row["name"];

$sql="UPDATE my_table SET active='Y' WHERE id=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: Your first `SELECT` query seems somewhat non determistic to me.  Shouldn't you be using an ordering there?

Comment: What's the point of the SELECT anyway?

Comment: I want to get the NAME value and of course ID for updating.

Comment: Figure out the _ordering_ of your `SELECT` (`LIMIT 1` is a bit meaningless without an ordering), then check out the @Strawberry answer below.

Comment: By LIMIT 1 I understand to get 1 row that fulfills the condition WHERE. I don't know why is this wrong? Should I use ORDER BY active LIMIT 1?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't return values in an update statement, so if you want to do 2 actions (select & update) you need 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

No SELECT required...

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET active = 'Y' 
 WHERE active = 'N'
 ORDER 
    BY id 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I still need to use SELECT query... how do I get name value?

Comment: I don't understand you, as I said I need also know the NAME value, but UPDATE is only returns the number of rows that were actually changed.

Comment: it seems like r0b0urd0n is right I need two queries for that. I'm not good in mysql so I thought it can be done in one query.

Comment: I said it on the beginning "I want to select first available value 'name' ...." sorry it this was not enough clear and also from my two queries you can see what I'm trying to do :-)

Comment: I suggest you see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. r0b0urd0n may be correct but, either way, your present code is flawed.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you show me the right way. Please edit your answer for that.

Comment: I can't. Not without knowing how you define 'first'. I have nothing further to contribute at this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `name` to be returned then, you can execute only `UPDATE` statement. It will return you the `count` of rows that got updated.

Assuming `id` is the primary key, based on the count returned, you can check whether a row existed or not (e.g. if `count` is 0 then row didn't exist and if `count` is 1, row existed). This will be as good as `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = $id`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  update my_table set active = 'Y' 
  where id in 
 (select id from (SELECT id, name FROM my_table WHERE active='N' LIMIT 1)h);
```